# php exec another PHP page

Tags: php

I've been told (from a previous question of mine) that to run an external PHP script, i could use `exec` or `curl`.

I've started looking into `exec` and it seems simple, however I believe I am doing something incorrectly.

Is this not the correct, simple way to just run a page (and not require any data returned)?

`exec("/folder/some_page.php?var=" . defined_variable);`

I've tried different combinations of relative and direct links, with/without starting with a slash.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: If it's on your server - why not use `include`? "that to run an external PHP script, i could use exec or curl." --- I'm sure you get it wrong.

Comment: I don't want any of the data/output that is on that page. just want it to run on the server and no more. If I use `include`, then the resulting data is `include`d on my page, which is no bueno.

Comment: to get the best answer in your case - you need to provide more details of what you're trying to do. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @zerkms, no I think it's a pretty clear question. I want a PHP page to execute, and do not need any of the resulting data.

Comment: you haven't explained why `include` is wrong. The thing is - newbies often follow the wrong idea thus ask about wrong solutions.

Comment: Please see my first response to your first comment.

Comment: I see it. And I don't know how "data/output" is related to `include`. As I said - the best idea is to explain what task you're trying to solve - to get the best solution. Because what you're trying to do now doesn't look right.

Comment: OK. If you' are on page A and use `include(page b)`,  page b's output/html will now be shown/written on page A. So back to my comment, "If I use include, then the resulting data is included on my page, which is no bueno.". Sorry If I was unclear.

Comment: if you don't want it to output anything - just capture it with `ob_*` functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`exec()` runs a program, not a script. In your case, you'd need to call the `php` executable and pass it the path to the folder on the server. You'd also have to use the command line syntax for passing query parameters, not the URL syntax.

See here for more details on command-line PHP usage (which is what `exec()` is essentially doing, minus the interactive component): http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php

Answer (score 2):

Execute the php:

```
exec("/folder/some_page.php $var1 $var2 $var3 $varn");
```

Get the variables in some_page.php:

```
$var1=$argv[1];
$var2=$argv[2];
$var3=$argv[3];
$var4=$argv[n];
```